# Refactoring how react/node handles response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using a react frontend and fetching data from my node server. I feel like my code looks a bit redundant, is there a better way to refactor all this?

App.js

```
  searchStock = async (value) => {
    let priceURL = `/stock/${ value }/price`
    // fetch price data
    fetch(priceURL)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          res.json()
          .then( (result) => {
            this.setState({
              price: result
            })
          })
        }
        else {
          console.log("Something went wrong...")
        }
      })
     }
```

server.js

```
app.get('/stock/:symbol/price', (req, res) => {
  const token = 'abcde123'
  const symbol = req.params.symbol
  const apiURL = `https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${symbol}/price?token=T${token}`

  fetch(apiURL)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.status)
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then((data) => {
          res.json(data)
        });
      }
      else {
        res.sendStatus(response.status)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As these two code segments live in different apps (frontend and backend) I don't think there's a pretty way of DRYing this.

Comment: Yes, the `App.js` is react, and the `server.js` is node.

Comment: Unless you manage to share code between these two applications, you'll have to live with duplicated HTTP request handling, @jj008.

Comment: most node modules can be used on both sides just create some library module that is environment agnostic and allows you to substitute elements that are depending on the environment

Answer (score 0):

Introduce library file with fetching logic

*src/helper.js*

```
exports.fetchHelper = (url) => fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(response.status)
    }
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

and use respectively

*app.js*

```
import { fetchHelper } from 'src/helper'; // or whatever else your bundler setup requires

searchStock = async (value) => {
  const priceURL = `/stock/${ value }/price`;
  await fetchHelper(priceURL).then((result) => {
    this.setState({
      price: result
    })
  })
}
```

*server.js*

```
const fetchHelper = require('src/helper').fetchHelper;

app.get('/stock/:symbol/price', (req, res) => {
  const token = 'abcde123'
  const symbol = req.params.symbol
  const apiURL = `https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/${symbol}/price?token=T${token}`
  fetchHelper(apiURL).then((response) => {
    res.json(data);
  })
```

Or something similar...

Comment: did this help you in any way?